# How to set a mage/cookies cookie expiration date to the user's session

Tags: magento2, javascript, frontend, requirejs, cookie

### Default jQuery method

In my JS (loaded using Require JS) I'm setting a cookie like so:

```
$.cookie('hideStickyBanner', 1);
```

This sets a cookie with the expiration date of session which is exactly what I need.

### Magento method

But when I try using the `mage/cookies` method the expiration date defaults to approx 4 days time.

```
$.mage.cookies.set('hideStickyBannerMagento', 1);
```

### Question

**How can I use the `$.mage.cookies.set();` function but have the expiration date be the user's session?**

I tried this but the expiration still defaulted to 4 days time:

```
$.mage.cookies.set('hideStickyBannerMagento', 1, {
    expires: 0
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$.mage.cookies.set('name', 'value', {lifetime: -1});`

Which seems a little crazy, but here's why...

The source for `mage/cookies` can be found `lib/web/mage/cookies.js`. The set method, at least in 2.2.0, sets the expires value with this little snippet:

```
expires = lifetimeToExpires(options, this.defaults) || options.expires;
```

I don't know why this was done, but is looks backwards to me. The `lifetimeToExpires` will add the default lifetime to the current time or to `options.expires` anytime `options.lifetime` or `defaults.lifetime` is greater than 0. That means any value passed in `options.expires` won't be output to the cookie as is.

Setting `options.lifetime` to any negative number will cause `lifetimeToExpires` to return `null`. Later in the `set` method when the cookie is created no expiration value will be passed and it will default to session.

Comment: Ahh I didn't try negative numbers! Agreed it seems weird how they've implemented it, thanks.